# /boot/.IpTables use high cpu in my server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, vps

i am newbie in network administrator..

One week ago, my server work perfectly. My Server can serves  600++ users at the same time and only use 40% cpu.

Today there is something wrong with my server. My server shows 100% cpu usage when it serves 100 users at the same time.

After i check, i found a process /boot/.IpTables that use high cpu.

**What happen with my server? Is my server hacked or what?**

This is SS my server process :
[image]

Comment: What **is** /boot/.Iptables ? No distribution I have used comes with hidden files in the /boot directory ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like your system has been had.  I did some googling for /boot/.Iptables, and it appears to be malware.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/407457/help-my-server-has-been-hacked-iptables-and-iptablex-in-boot
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=46704

My personal recommendation would be to take the machine of the network immediately, clone the drive to a USB disk, and re-install (preferably w/ a new set of passwords, and all available patches applied).